# Running code after view has rendered in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a line of code I wish to run after a view script has rendered, but I want this code to be placed in the action.

This is action specific and only updates a flag in the database, so it seems like overkill to utilise a plugin just for this.

What other options do I have? Could I register an abstract plugin that I can extend and hook into `dispatchLoopShutdown()` or `routeShutdown()` from the specific action I am in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default 'View' is the last thing that the pointer will pass through.
you can:

```
$this->_helper->removeHelper('viewRenderer');
```

to globally remove views and then do the rest of action.

Actually, in many of my codes, I load views in chunks and have not faced any issues whilst rendering them before. Example, if I do:

```
$this->view->shouldGoinHeader;
// some actions here
$this->view->someHere;
// some more action thing
```

It works! So you can update a flag on your database using try catch if you are checking if view has been rendered.

If something is getting executed, you might want to post your codes?